# Allowing everyone in my domain to edit a Google Calendar

Tags: google-workspace, google-calendar

When you share a Google Doc, there's an option to give everyone in your domain permission to view and edit the document. As far as I can tell, there isn't an equivalent option for Google Calendar. There's an option to "Share this calendar with everyone in the organization," but all the options are read-only, there's no option to allow others in the organization to add or edit events. Am I missing something? Is this something the domain administrator can enable?

Answer (score 5):

You can use Google Groups to solve your problem. Have the Super Administrator [create a group containing all users in your Google Apps account](https://support.google.com/a/answer/66338?hl=en), then [add this group's email address to the calendar](https://support.google.com/a/answer/117596?hl=en) with the "Make Changes to Events" permission level.

One complication is that giving a group permission to a calendar doesn't add that calendar to the user's calendar ACL - in other words, they will not see it show up in their calendar list after you give the group permission. Your Super Admin can use the powerful [Google Apps Manager](https://github.com/jay0lee/GAM) tool to add this calendar to the calendar list of all users using the below syntax ([source](https://github.com/jay0lee/GAM/wiki/CalendarExamples)), replacing `<calendar email>` with the actual email of your calendar:

```
gam user all users update calendar <calendar email> selected true
```

Also, as you noticed, there isn't currently a Super Admin setting to allow all organization users to modify a calendar - only to change the visibility:
[image]