# Allow some guests to edit a specific event

Tags: google-calendar

I have a recurring event in my Google Calendar that has multiple guests.

I would like to allow some of the guests, but not others, to edit the event such as add guests, change times, edit the description, etc.

How can I give edit  permissions for the event to specific guests only?

Answer (score 1):

Google Calendar hasn't a built-in feature to do this. One workaround is to give event edit privileges in the calendar to those *trusted guests* , so it's might be a good idea to use a non-default calendar for these events where you want to delegate tasks for few events.

---

From *Share your calendar with someone*

> **Change visibility settings for an individual event**
> Your events automatically have the same access permissions as your calendar. However, you can edit the visibility for each event. Learn more about changing the visibility setting for an event.

---

Resources

- [Share your calendar with someone](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37082?hl=en)
- [Create an event](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/72143?hl=en)

Related

- [Allowing everyone in my domain to edit a Google Calendar](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/59141/88163)